# keras VGG19 add Input layer got graph disconnected error

Tags: python, keras

I have below code, I do not understand why this is graph disconnected error? I do not know what is wrong.

```
def create_model_tl_attn_posInputOnly(input_shape):
    print("start creating model - transfer learning ...")

    emb = embed_encoding2d(input_shape[0], input_shape[1], input_shape[2]) # this is from another class

    img_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
    base_model = vgg19.VGG19(include_top=False, input_shape=input_shape, weights="imagenet")
    base_model.trainable = False
    x = base_model(img_input + emb)
    
    flat1 = Flatten()(x)
    class1 = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(flat1)
    dropout1 = Dropout(0.2)(class1)
    class2 = Dense(512, activation='relu')(dropout1)
    dropout2 = Dropout(0.2)(class2)
    
    output = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(dropout2) 
    
    model = Model(inputs=img_input, outputs=output)
    
    return model
```

I changed to `model = Model(inputs=base_model.inputs, outputs=output)`, but still got `graph disconnected` error.

Comment: `x = base_model(img_input + emb])` seems like there's a typo. Also what was your intention by adding them?

Comment: @Frightera, yes there is a typo, correct the typo still "graph disconnected" error. My intention is to adding ```img_input``` and ```emb```. I worked out code as below, however, do not know how to verify if ```input``` is the sum of ```img_input``` and ```emb```. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I update code as below, no error, however I do not know if the `input` is a sum of `img_input` and `emb`, how to check during training?

```
def create_model_tl_attn_posInputOnly(input_shape):
    print("start creating model - transfer learning ...")

    emb = embed_encoding2d(input_shape[0], input_shape[1], input_shape[2]) # this is from another class

    img_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
    base_model = vgg19.VGG19(include_top=False, input_shape=input_shape, weights="imagenet")
    base_model.trainable = False
    x = base_model(img_input + emb)
    x = base_model.layers[-1].output

    flat1 = Flatten()(x)
    class1 = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(flat1)
    dropout1 = Dropout(0.2)(class1)
    class2 = Dense(512, activation='relu')(dropout1)
    dropout2 = Dropout(0.2)(class2)
    
    output = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(dropout2) 
    
    model = Model(inputs=base_model.inputs, outputs=output)
    
    return model
```